# How to get TYPO3 Route Enhancers to properly work with custom extension (TYPO 3 v10)

Tags: yaml, typo3, typo3-10.x

**Problem:**

In TYPO3 v10, I have a custom extension with a simple "item" model that utilizes the System Categories. I am trying to have the system category URL segments (e.g. "www.mywebsite.com/categories/**books**") to route to the listitemsbycategory action in my Item controller to show the items by that particular category. I have in fact a page that "contains" my extension's FE Plugin (Myextensionplugin) located at "www.mywebsite.com/categories/". I just need the URL "www.mywebsite.com/categories/books" to actually "call" the listitemsbycategory action so I can use the category's title (books in this case) to fetch the records of that category. Having placed the below code in my site's config.yaml code doesn't work however. It simply redirects "www.mywebsite.com/categories/books" to the homepage - that's it. I've played around with the config file for about an entire day - nothing seems to work.

**To Summarize what I'm trying to achieve:**

Make "www.mywebsite.com/categories/books" call the listitemsbycategory action of my controller on the [www.mywebsite.com/categories/](http://www.mywebsite.com/categories/) page.

**Config.yaml code (only routeEnhancers part):**

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyextensionCategory:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [0,1,2]
    extension: Myextension
    plugin: Myextensionplugin
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/categories/{category_title}'
        _controller: 'Item::listitemsbycategory'
        _arguments:
          category_title: category
    defaultController: 'Item::listitemsbycategory'
    requirements:
      category_title: '^[a-z0-9].*$'
    aspects:
      category_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: slug
```

Comment: On which page have you placed your plugin? Your configuration is saying on pages UID 0, 1 and 2 (`limitToPages`). I doubt that your plugin is integrated on page UID = 0...

Comment: The route path doesn't need the "/categories" ("/{category_title}) should be enough, since the plugin-page already delivers that part. Apart from that i don't see any obvious errors in your config

Comment: Thanks **Christoph Kern** and **Julian Hofmann** - Both of your comments helped me finding a working solution. Indeed, the limitToPages needed to be set correctly to just the one page that I was actually using the plugin on, AND the "categories" needed to be stripped out of the routePath section of the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to this particular issue -- the limitToPages needed to be set correctly to just the one page that I was actually using the plugin on, AND the "categories" part needed to be stripped out of the routePath section of the code.

Thanks to @ChristophKern and @JulianHofmann for providing the necessary hints!.